# Developing a chrome extension using the chrome.enterprise API's

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-workspace

We are developing a chrome extension for chromebook devices and I'm looking to use the chrome.enterprise API's (for example: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_deviceAttributes). As stated in the documentation the API's are "only for extensions pre-installed by policy".

I'm trying to test my extension on a chromebook that is managed by a GSuite for education environment. However, I'm unsure of how to test such an extension before publishing it. I can locally install the extension but then it is not pre-installed by policy and the chrome.enterprise API's are not available. I also don't see any way of installing a non-published extension through GSuite.

The only avenue that seemed promising is to create an .crx and host it. (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/linux_hosting). However, the extension does not get installed. When downloading it directly i get an *crx_required_proof_missing* error and when installing it through GSuite I find a *parsing manifest failed* error in the chromebooks logfiles.

What is the proper way of developing extensions using API's that are "only for extensions pre-installed by policy"?

Thanks.

Comment: Try specifying `--whitelisted-extension-id=yourExtensionId` in [command line](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags).

Comment: That did it, thank you!

Comment: To those looking in the future, this flag has been renamed to `allowlisted-extension-id`. The old flag has been deprecated and will be removed soon. (Reference: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/common/switches.cc;l=23?q=whitelisted-extension-id&ss=chromium